# Delphi - Prime Numbers

Tags: delphi, pascal

A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
What I'm doing is this to check if the number is prime or not :

```
begin
writeln('give a number ');
readln(N);  S := 0;
for I := 1 to N do
if N mod I = 0 then
 S := S + 1 ;

 if S = 2 then
 writeln('Prime')
 else
 writeln('not prime');
 sleep(50000);

end.
```

I'm now trying to get all the prime numbers between 1 and 100 (or any other number) using this :

```
begin
writeln('give a number ');
readln(N);

for I := 1 to N do  begin
        S := 0;
 for J := 1 to I do
  begin
 if I mod J = 0 then
 S := S +1 ;  if S = 2 then
       writeln(I);

 end;
   end;
sleep(500000000000);
 end.
```

But it's not reallyworking .

Comment: It's not duplicate of anything , because I'm asking about the second code and not the first .
@MartynA why is that ? Logically the prime only accept division of 1 and him self , which makes it two numbers . so I suppose that how It works , now yes .. the problem is on the second code (loop) .

Comment: I was able to fix it , answer in second post . ty everyone .

Comment: When you ask other people to help you with a problem you should provide a better description of the problem than _"it's not reallyworking "_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it :

```
begin
writeln('give a number ');
readln(N);

  for I  := 1 to N do begin
 S := 0;
 for J := 1 to I do
 begin
if I mod J = 0 then
        S := S +1 ;

 end;   
 if S = 2 then writeln(i);


 end; sleep(50000);
end.
```

Comment: you can replace your Sleep call with Readln(); if you want to prevent closing of the command prompt...

Comment: I would suggest you to read a bit more about prime numbers too. Some mathematical results would allow you to optimize your code. For instance, you don't need to check all integers up to N, because there is a theorem saying that a prime divisor of a number must me smaller than the square root of that number. Then you'd have to test just up to the first integer greater than the square root of N and change your condition to S - 1, since I would never reach N to count the second number qho divides N, i.e., N itself.

Comment: Great for a function:
function getPrimelist(n: integer): array of integer;
var i, j, s: integer;
begin
 setlength(result, n+1)
 for I:= 1 to N do begin
   S:= 0;
   for J:= 1 to I do begin
     if I mod J = 0 then
        S:= S +1 ;
   end;   
   if S = 2 then result[j]:= i; //writeln(itoa(i));
 end;
end;